# Почему выдает ошибку в Delphi?!

Tags: delphi

Почему выдает ошибку в Delphi?! После создания Формы нажимаю на ячейку Баттом. И сразу же выдает ошибку, где программа сама на автомате пишет код.[image: В разделе type.]

Comment: `ctrl+f9` и ошибку компилятора в студию. То что редактор подчеркнул что-то не значит что там ошибка. 2009я среда вообще дженерики почти красным подсвечивала, к примеру.

Comment: Добро пожаловать на StackOverflow. Что есть "ячейка Баттом"?

Comment: @Igor дабл клик на кнопку видимо имеется в виду в редакторе форм :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В список uses добавьте  Vcl.StdCtrls.

Comment: Спасибо, помогло!!!

Comment: Примите ответ, если он решает вашу проблему и удовлетворяет условиям.

Comment: Достаточно просто сохранить проект, не нужно руками писать.